# Cannot process converting csv file to arrays in android

Tags: java, android, csv

I'm very very new to android & JAVA, and I'm trying to learn writing android apps by myself. I met a problem when I was trying to read values from a csv file and plot them out. To be more specific, I was trying to modify Androidplot example.

The original Androidplot example works, while my modified one never work...I tried to find the problem but I failed failed failed...Every time I tried to debug the codes, ActivityThread.java just pops out, and there's a little arrow pointing to the following codes:

```
catch (Exception e) {
        if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Unable to start activity " + component
                + ": " + e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me what the problem really is? Any help will be much appreciated =)

Below is my modified codes:

```
package edu.ius.rwisman.AndroidPlotExample;

import android.app.Activity;  

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.series.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class AndroidPlotExampleActivity extends Activity
{

private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;

@SuppressWarnings("null")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Initialize our XYPlot reference:
    mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);
    Number[] series1Numbers = null;
    Number[] series2Numbers = null;
    int row = 0;
    // Create two arrays of y-values to plot:
    try {

        File file = new File("/home/hanrui/workspace/table.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        reader.readLine();
        String line = null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null&&row<24){
            String item[] = line.split(",");

            String last = item[item.length-1];
            int value = Integer.parseInt(last);
            series1Numbers[row] = value;
            series2Numbers[row] = value;
            row++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries:
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
            Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),          // SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value
            "Series1");                             // Set the display title of the series

    // Same as above, for series2
    XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, 
            "Series2");

    // Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer:
    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
            Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),                   // line color
            Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),                   // point color
            Color.rgb(150, 190, 150));              // fill color (optional)

    // Add series1 to the xyplot:
    mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    // Same as above, with series2:
    mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series2, new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 200), Color.rgb(0, 0, 100),
            Color.rgb(150, 150, 190)));


    // Reduce the number of range labels
    mySimpleXYPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);

    // By default, AndroidPlot displays developer guides to aid in laying out your plot.
    // To get rid of them call disableAllMarkup():
    mySimpleXYPlot.disableAllMarkup();
}
}
```

Comment: Among the utilities you should have for android development is "adb.exe", run "adb.exe logcat" to see the log which will provide you with exactly what kind of exception, in which file and even what line the problem is!

Comment: Usually debug info (like the one from LogCat) contains the number of line within the source file where the exception happens. Without knowing that line it's difficult to find the issue. Try to find the stacktrace and post it here.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I checked LogCat while there's nothing much there, but there's some error reported in DDMS:- Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:397)
 at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:102)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

Comment: It is NOT a good idea to use `@SuppressWarnings("null")`! If you're getting a null-warning during compile time, then you can be pretty sure that it's not going to work when running!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running an Android application it is run on the phone (emulator or an actual device in itself) and thus this file will most likely not be found:

`File file = new File("/home/hanrui/workspace/table.csv");`

After your try-catch-statement, check to see if `series1Numbers` equals null.

**Edit:**

I noticed something, you're never initializing your array of Number:

`Number[] series1Numbers = null;`.

Java isn't PHP, in PHP the array would be created directly but in Java this is not the case. You need to call `series1Numbers = new Number[10];` where `10` is the size of the array. I do recommend using ArrayList instead, as that can have a dynamical size.